# Django ORM вывод последних записей из связанной таблицы

Tags: python, django

Имеется две модели:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=_('participants'))

class Message(models.Model):
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, verbose_name=_('dialog'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('author'))
    txt = models.TextField(_('text of message'), blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
```

Во view надо выбрать не просто все диалоги конкретного пользователя, но и так же данные о последнем сообщении в каждом диалоге.

Вопрос: возможно ли с помощью Django ORM сделать это не используя цикл и дополнительных связей? И если да, то, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view.py**

```
def some_view(request):
    inner_qs = Message.objects.order_by('-created')
    prefetcher = Prefetch('message_set', queryset=inner_qs, to_attr='messages')
    ctx = {
        'dialogs': (Dialog.objects
                     .prefetch_related(prefetcher)
                     .filter(participants=request.user))
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', ctx)
```

**models.py**

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def latest_message(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'messages') and len(self.messages) > 0:
            return self.messages[0]
        return None
```

**some_template.html**

```
{% for dialog in dialogs %}
    {{ dialog.latest_message }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Вопрос был как раз в том, как сделать чтобы избежать запросы к БД в цикле. В вашем варианте при 100 диалогах у пользователя, будет 100 одинаковых запросов к базе. По крайней мере об этом говорит debug-toolbar.

Comment: Исправил. Теперь при любом количестве диалогов запроса будет два.

Comment: Почти, но нет. В таком случае будет один запрос на все диалоги и по 1 запросу на каждую итерацию цикла в шаблоне. Если я правильно читал документацию, то, обращение к методу модели делает новый запрос к БД. В данном случае это last(). Ваш пример проверил на двух диалогах и получил два дублирующих запроса. А если написать вот так {{ dialog.message_set.last.author }} и {{ dialog.message_set.last.txt }} получаю 4 дубля, то есть 1 запрос на каждый last()

Comment: Ваш вопрос оказался сложнее и интереснее, чем показался на первый взгляд :) Азарта добавляет, что у меня нет возможности проверять свои предположения. Попробуйте новый вариант.

Comment: Отлично. Ваш вариант работает как надо. Проверял на 2-х и 3-х диалогах. Но во view надо добавить select_related для inner_qs, иначе при попытке вывести автора отдельно получаются дубли. inner_qs = Message.objects.select_related().order_by('-created'). Это просто для истории :) Спасибо, очень помогли.